# Regmatches in R not working

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to add a column to a data set in R. The column should be the initials from a name column. I am trying to use `lapply` and passing in a function to get the initials - however, I can't get this regexp to work.

```
pattern <- "(\b[a-zA-Z])"
str<-"MICHAEL,  JENSON F"
m <- regexpr(pattern,str,perl=TRUE)
regmatches(str,m)
```

Returns character(0)

How can I have R return a list of matches of a string? I want regmatches to return M J and F.

Comment: This isn't very nice, but `library(stringr); substr(str_extract_all(str,"\\b[a-zA-Z]+")[[1]],1,1)` works ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks ben, just read about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems: `\b` must be escaped and you should use `gregexpr` instead of `regexpr` because the latter returns only the first match.

```
pattern <- "(\\b[a-zA-Z])"
str<-"MICHAEL,  JENSON F"
m <- gregexpr(pattern,str,perl=TRUE)
regmatches(str,m)[[1]]
# [1] "M" "J" "F"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out the stringr library.

```
str_match_all(str, "(\\b[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]* ?")
```